# redirect to https using nodejs and express in Heroku

Tags: node.js, http, express, https, server

I am hosting my webpage on Heroku and want to redirect to HTTPS. I am using Nodejs and Express.

I tried this code but when I visit the page the following error occurs:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74i1v.png)

I tried so hard to redirect my page to HTTPS but can't manage to do it. I would appreciate your help!

```
var express        = require("express");
    var app            = express();
    var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
    var nodemailer     = require("nodemailer");
    var favicon        = require('serve-favicon');
    var path           = require('path');
    var mongoose       = require ('mongoose');
    const sslRedirect = require('heroku-ssl-redirect')



app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) { // eslint-disable-line
  if (/^http$/.test(req.protocol)) {
    const host = req.headers.host.replace(/:[0-9]+$/g, '') // strip the port # if any
    return res.redirect(301, `https://${host}${req.url}`)
  }

  return next()
})
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/jobs", function(req, res){
  res.render("jobs");
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home");
});

app.get("/galerie", function(req, res){
  res.render("gallerie");
});

app.get("/team", function(req, res){
  res.render("team");
});

app.get("/uns", function(req, res){
    res.render("uns");
});

app.get("/contact", function(req, res) {
   res.render("contact");
});


    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    const ip = process.env.IP || "127.0.0.1";
    app.listen(port,function(){
        console.log("Server has started .... at port "+ port+" ip: "+ip);
    });
```

Comment: Is the https version of your site actually working? The error page you showed seems to indicate that HTTPS isn't working at all, you'll want to get that working before trying to redirect to it from http.

Comment: How sould I do that? Can you help me with it? I am deploying to Heroku. Please bear with me, this is my first time I am doing this

Comment: I don't really use Heroku but it seems like this is a pretty good place to start https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl

Comment: this doesn't help.

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more specific. We can't help if we don't understand what problems you're running into. The article linked describes a way to manually upload a certificate, or links off to an automated certificate manager for paid instances. Either of those will allow you to setup TLS/SSL for your application. After that you can then try and redirect from http -> https. If you have specific questions about the articles then you should ask those questions, but open ended "I can't do a thing" aren't very easy to answer and may get this question closed as "too broad".